# API to check Periscope User is Online

Tags: periscope

I've scoured for any information regarding an Open API for Periscope.

I have a twitter feed, that should only show if Periscope is Live (the said user will share the broadcast via Twitter).

I can parse the word "IS LIVE" but then I'd have to parse multiple languages.

I'm looking to check an API if the user is Online in periscope, if so, then display the latest twitter feed (which is the broadcast).

There was this User Online button that could be generated

https://www.periscope.tv/embed

it calls an api like https://embed.periscope.tv/user/bpsdmik.json
but it seems that the certificate is invalid, so I keep getting errors ..

Any help / workarounds would be much appreciated!

I've Searched OPEN Periscope, but mostly requires an Authentication token etc.

Answer (score 0):

There is no open API for Periscope. At least, not that I'm aware of. Which would explain your difficulty in finding anything. The closest thing would be the [Unofficial Periscope API](https://static.pmmlabs.ru/OpenPeriscope), documented by Pmmlabs (the same folks who run the [OpenPeriscope](https://github.com/Pmmlabs/OpenPeriscope) project). However, as you've already discovered, most of the calls to the Periscope API, including all user-related calls, require an auth token.

Outside of using the API or screen scraping, the only other way I can think of to tell if a user is live or not is to try accessing their Periscope page directly. When you go to a user's Periscope page at https://www.pscp.tv/{userId}, Periscope will redirect you to that users most recent broadcast, where you can parse the broadcast id from the redirect URL. Once you have the broadcast id of the most recent broadcast, you can use the following API call (which does not require an auth token):

https://api.periscope.tv/api/v2/getAccessPublic?token={broadcastId}

... to determine whether the broadcast is live or not. Look at the JSON response and if the "type" field equals "StreamTypeReplay", then it's a replay, otherwise it's a live broadcast.